# how to use vagrant for oracle cloud infrastructure

Tags: vagrant, oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, vagrant-aws

Like **vagrant-aws**, I am looking for plugin to work with Oracle cloud Infrastructure.

I found [vagrant-oci](https://github.com/stephenpearson/vagrant-oci), but not sure if it works. Didn't get proper example for it.
Followed steps and tried with this plugin but no luck.

failed with following error

```
/root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.6/gems/oci-2.9.0/lib/oci/api_client.rb:477:in `handle_non_success_response': The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect. (OCI::Errors::ServiceError)
```

If anyone has used it already or if have alternatives, please suggest.

Comment: I would suggest opening a github issue against that project so the project owner sees your issue. He may not check StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jodoglevy that it looks like a possible authentication problem.  It would be helpful to see your Vagrantfile (suitably redacted is ok) but a quick test is to take the profile name and the config file path you specified in your Vagrantfile and run this:

```sh
oci iam availability-domain list --profile <profilename> --config-file <configfilepath>
```

If that does work then Vagrant must be having trouble reading your config file or OCI API key for some reason.  It looks as though you're running Vagrant as root.  Could your OCI config be under a different user account?

Incidentally one regression in the driver is that it doesn't support the newer non-PEM style ssh keys that MacOS's ssh-keygen now outputs by default.  If you have one of those (with "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----" in the preamble) then for now you'll need to generate another key with `ssh-keygen -m PEM -f <filename>` to force the requisite PEM format.

FYI: The full list of configuration options, if you need them, are available here: https://github.com/stephenpearson/vagrant-oci/blob/master/lib/vagrant-oci/config.rb

Comment: Thanks!!  Some how managed to solve Auth problem. In config, i didn't get configuration for vcn_id, nsg_id. I am expecting here to use already created VCN, Network Security Group, etc.

Comment: If the subnet ocid is fixed and you happen to know it then you can specify `oci.subnet_id`.  Otherwise you can specify the vcn and subnet compartment and dns label and search for it, as in this example: https://github.com/stephenpearson/vagrant-oci/blob/master/Vagrantfile.sample/Vagrantfile

Comment: i can see only support  for subnet, not for nsg.

Comment: There is currently no support for nsg.  That would have to be added as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates an authentication error, which OCI services return if the credentials passed to authenticate are incorrect. Please make sure you've followed the instructions [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm) to construct your credentials and config file correctly.

Comment: did. Created and passed valid config file, but I doubt the vagrant-oci plugin read it from the config.